# How was "patronage" actually transferred in Medici Florence?

Tags: art, renaissance

The Medicis commissioned art and patronized artists.  By what mechanism was this achieved?  Did someone literally just hand a bag of florins to an artist?  I'm interested in the whole process, from asking for the work through to, I guess, estimates of cost, then actual transfer of funds/material/?

I'm looking for the physical method of fund transfer. As an example, at work today I might submit a request to purchasing or an expense claim. What was the equivalent and how exactly did it get paid out?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Have you checked [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronage)?  I rather suspect that the patron just let it be known that he would pay the bills.

Comment: Yes, I do get that. I may need to clarify the question. I'm looking for the physical method of fund transfer. As an example, at work today I might submit a request to purchasing or an expense claim. What was the equivalent and how exactly did it get paid out?

Comment: An article [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290223656_A_Taxonomy_of_Art_Patronage_in_Renaissance_Italy) may offer some useful information, but it is mainly focused on various *types* of *patrons*, though it does mention in passing commissions, contracts and salaries at various points. An extensive bibliography may assist your research however.